# Product detail and images in django problem

Tags: python, django, image, product

I'm trying to create a simple car dealership app and i'm stuck. I have searched days and i have tried so many times to fix this but i can't. What i'm doing wrong i don't know and my brain is not working anymore. Thanks for help.

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'car_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '2021-ram-1500-trx-crew-cab-4x4-57-box'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'car_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '2021-ram-1500-trx-crew-cab-4x4-57-box'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users*\Desktop\Testdealer\envdealer\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users*\Desktop\Testdealer\envdealer\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.urls import reverse

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CATEGORY = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Used', 'Used')
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY)
    image_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    body_style = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    stock_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mpg = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    exterior_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    interior_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    drivetrain = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(1940, datetime.date.today().year+1)]
    year = models.IntegerField(
        ('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    power = models.IntegerField()
    fuel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('car_detail', kwargs={
    #         'car_id': self.id
    #     })

class CarImage(models.Model):
    """
    The Product Image table.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(
        Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="car_image")
    image = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="image",
        help_text="Upload a product image",
        upload_to="images/",
        default="images/default.png",
    )
    alt_text = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Alturnative text",
        help_text="Please add alturnative text",
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Car Image"
        verbose_name_plural = "Car Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Car, Dealer, CarImage
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def car_detail(request, id, slug):
    cars = Car.objects.get(pk=id)
    images = CarImage.objects.filter(car_id=id)
    context = {'cars': cars, 'images': images}
    return render(request, 'car_detail.html', context)
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from cars import views

..........

path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>', views.car_detail, name="car_detail"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`.get_absolute_url()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) of the `Car` model only specifies the `slug`, not the `id` parameter:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # ⋮

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #                add id to the context ↓
        return reverse('car_detail', kwargs={'id': self.pk, 'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Also I believe the actual slug `2021-ram-1500-trx-crew-cab-4x4-57-box` won't match the Django's `slug` pattern because of "x" character.

Comment: @RomanMiroshnychenko: no that will match since `slug` uses `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+` so one or more characters in that character group (https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/urls/converters.py#L36). This means that all lowercase chars `a-z` are part of the character group, and it thus will match `x` as well. It would not match the times character (&times; in HTML, or × as unicode), but I checked the input and it is a simple lowercase `x`